# jQuery buttonset change

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-button

I'm new to jQuery and thought I would use its buttonset instead of some radio buttons on my application.  Documentation here:  http://jqueryui.com/demos/button/#radio

How do I add a handler to an event when the set of buttons changes value?

Here is a snippet of the code I tried:

```
$('input.tod_quant').change(function() {
    alert('TEST');
});
```

And then later on in the HTML:

```
<span id="tod_quant" class="buttonset">
        <input type="radio" id="tod_quant5" name="tod_quant" value="5" /><label for="tod_quant5">5-Minute</label>
        <input type="radio" id="tod_quant60" name="tod_quant" checked="checked" value="60" /><label for="tod_quant60">60-Minute</label>
        </span>
```

The "change" event never fires.  Is there even a change event?  How can I do this?  Furthermore, is there any documentation with an example?  http://jqueryui.com has plenty of examples, and not a single one that I can find shows any events firing.  I suppose my ignorance of jQuery isn't exactly helping the situation.

Any help would be most appreciated.  Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ha!  Problem solved.  I've been hacking at this all day, and it was right in front of me.

I just needed to change how I was selecting the element to this:

```
$('#tod_quant')
```

Comment: Your answer flashed up as I was writing the same... shucks!

Answer (score 10):

There's no `change` event for buttons in jQuery-UI.

You should listen to change or click event of the underlying radio-buttons:

http://jsfiddle.net/marcosfromero/kr2Xc/

Comment: While this is true, you can listen to a change event applied to the button set. Seems like a jQuery easter egg but this works fine:`$('#tod_quant').buttonset().change(function(){//do stuff});`

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem, and I solved this as below:
I created an event handler for labels:

```
$('.label-class').click(LabelClicked);
$('.input-class').change(InputChanged);
function LabelClicked() {
    var input = $('#' + $(this).attr('for'));
    if(input) 
        input.trigger('change'); 
    return true;
}
function InputChanged() {
    //do your work with this event
}
```

no other way! I tested several ways and finally decided to do this

Comment: As an additional note for those using dynamically created checkboxes, you must include the event handler AFTER the call to buttonset().  If you are getting the fields from ajax it must be done on every update. It is obvious when you think about it but I spent a fair amount time checking for typos and syntax before I realized I created a handler on something that didn't exist.

Answer (score -1):

```
    <script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#radio" ).buttonset();
    });
    </script>



<div class="demo">

<form>
    <div id="radio">
        <input type="radio" id="radio1" name="radio" /><label for="radio1">Choice 1</label>
        <input type="radio" id="radio2" name="radio" checked="checked" /><label for="radio2">Choice 2</label>
        <input type="radio" id="radio3" name="radio" /><label for="radio3">Choice 3</label>
    </div>
</form>
```

use this code and check whether you are including the jquery.js and jqueryui.js files or not.